# Why my Bool value changes in catch block even if there was no error?

Tags: c#

I'm still learning c# and came across this problem , i wanted to make a program that make sure that the user enters an integer . but when i do this , i'm stuck in an infinite loop . Why the the bool b; variable change its value in catch block even if the user typed an integer ? 
My code :

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int n= 0;
        bool b = true;
        do {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine ("Enter an integer : ");
                n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
                b = false;
            } finally {
                Console.WriteLine (n);
            }
        } while(b == false);
    }
}
```

but i fixed the problem when i did this :

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int n= 0;
        bool b;
        do {
            try {
                b = true;
                Console.WriteLine ("Enter an integer : ");
                n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
                b = false;
            } finally {
                Console.WriteLine (n);
            }
        } while(b == false);
    }
}
```

can someone explain please ?

Comment: Because you set it to false on the first error, but never set it to true again, so it is going to loop until `b == true`, which will never happen.

Comment: You fixed it by resetting the `b` variable to `true` on each iteration. Previously, it was only set to `true` once, outside the loop, so if it was set to `false`, you were doomed.

Comment: omg i feel so dumb right now , i didn't notice that ^^' . Thank you!

Comment: Rather than using Convert, you should use b = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

Comment: I 100% agree with @bhmahler that you should use `int.TryParse` here instead of relying on exception handling for control flow.

Comment: Generally exceptions should be for exceptional cases. In your program its common if a user enters an invalid input.

Comment: i totally agree with you , i used Int.TryParse before but I try to learn how try catch work to get familiar with it .that's why i used it in this simple problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **b** variable is trapped as false forever, if the user doesn't enter a correct input. So, in the beginning of every loop the boolean variable needs to be set as "true" which was its default value. That is because every iteration should be a new try for the user to enter an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this just by using int.TryParse without a try catch block

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    int n= 0;
    bool b;
    do {
        Console.Write ("Enter an integer : ");
        b = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine (), out n);
    } while(!b);
    //int has been entered, now do something else...
}
```

You can simplify it even further by not even introducing the bool variable

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    int n;
    do {
        Console.Write ("Enter an integer : ");
    } while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine (), out n));
    //int has been entered, now do something else...
}
```

Comment: i did that before , but i'm learning how to use try catch to get familiar with it ^^

Comment: Understandable but in this case it’s not really the right design. Try catch is for an exception that may be unavoidable. In this case there is no reason to use code that will throw an exception.

Comment: Got it , Thank you !